# iOS - Recovering data from device after reset

Tags: ios, ipad, restore

I would like to give away my 1st Generation iPad. If I reset it by selecting **Reset All Content and Settings**, would it be possible for someone to restore the data (passwords, photos, etc.) which are currently on it?

Would it be possible to install some kind of restore or data rescue application and restore the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**. Generally it won't be possible to **recover** data from the iPad for someone else, once you have unlinked it from your Apple ID and erased it by selecting **Reset All Content and Settings**.

The data can be restored on the device by restoring from a backup from either computer or iCloud.

However, as you looking to give it away to a 3rd party, it is recommended to go through the instructions outlined in the Apple support document, [What to do before you sell or give away your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/ht201351) and follow each applicable steps.

Answer (score 2):

If the new User do not have to password for your appleID or an iTunes Backup, he'll not be able to restore any of your data after the iPad have been wiped.